# How to generate a database or reference in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I am new to LyX. I want to add bibliography but I don't have any database to insert. So how can I type the references directly in LyX or how to create a database and then insert it? Also is there any software which has to be installed for creating the data base?

Answer (score 1):

The database creation can be acomplished manually or with a program (somehow tautological). Common softwares are JabRef and BibDesk, whereas the latter one is only for MacOS. If you need more information about this softwares, ask another questions on this site. The manual way is also totally viable because you only have to respect the BibTeX syntax. (As LaTeX also LyX relies on BibTeX for the citing mechanism. *Hence no additional software is needed*.) In fact your database will be simple textfile named with `.bib` in the end to assure that LyX (LaTeX resp.) works correctly. An example for an entry in that database (following the BibTeX rules) would be:

```
@BOOK{Doe2013,
title = {Example Book},
publisher = {wilson},
year = {2013},
author = {Doe, John},
edition = {1}
}
```

In General every entry will have a unique key - in this case `Doe2013`, that can be used to cite this source. The example entry is intended to gather relevant data of a book. But more options are available here. For a detailed list of the possible entry types you can have a look at the wikipedia article on BibTeX (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) or ask more questions on this site.

To import data from your database into your document, LyX provides two different ways: Either you print all the entries (which I think you are looking for) or the ones you used to cite from. Anyways you find both options in the same LyX dialogue located in "Insert > 
List/TOC/BibTeX Bibliography".