# Image positioning in new page

Tags: floats, positioning

If i use the following code, my image is placed in the center of the page, horizontal as vertical. I think this happens, because the section above ended on the page before. I want it to go to the top of the page and then continue with text in a new page.
If i would insert new text above the image, it should move down only as much as necessary.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=15cm]{images/g550}\caption{G550 \cite{bild_g550}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\clearpage{}
```

I'm using the `scrrprt` class.

Comment: See http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=vertposfp and http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=floats to understand better how floats work.

Comment: Aside from your question: What is the group after `\clearpage` for? And it seems that you have a picture in your BibTeX bibliography. Which entry type do you used for it? Moreover you cite this picture in the caption of itself. That reference appeals quite short ranged. Are you really citing here?

Comment: I'm using LyX, the `{}` after `\clearpage`was automatically created <br> I'm not using BibTeX, it's just the bibliography function... There is an url in my bib to the page i got the image, because the used image doesnt belong to me. If this is not how it is made as usual, please tell me how it should be

Comment: @drrtyrokka, `\cite` is intended to be used for citations from bibliographical sources. If your picture is a source, you could declare is at one (the keyword to your further research is **BibTeX**), and use `\cite` later in the text to refer to it in order to cover an implication. But, all this normally holds if the source you cite from is published somewhere. If your actual picture isn't, it becomes a different story. However, I would also care for copyrights. If this isn't a problem, then normally mentioning the URL is enough. For this you definitely don't need `\cite`.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139737/how-to-generate-a-database-or-reference-in-bibliography/139749#139749) could help you for getting into *Lyx and BibTeX*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.
For me, adding the following Code in the preamble helped.

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
```